# Argument list in C: increment/decrement va_arg?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I'm trying to access the next or previous element when calling va_arg in an argument list. "n" is actually the length of the argument list.

```
va_list pointer;

va_start(pointer, n);
int temp = va_arg(pointer, int);
...
if(temp < va_arg(pointer, int))...
...

void va_end(va_list pointer)
```

Is it actually possible to swap two positions of the argument list?
Same thing like the swap of two integers in bubblesort.

Comment: From your code it seems like you might rather need an array...

Comment: it's possible, but as arguments to functions are passed by value, they will be destroyed upon returning to the main code.  What would be the purpose of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "list" you get from the `va_*` "functions" (they are most often implemented as preprocessor macros) is a part of the stack, and as a true stack you can only "pop" values of it.

So no you can't "swap" values, or go backwards. You can't even "push" values, only "pop".

If you want to swap values, you have to get both values into variables, and swap the values of those variables.

Comment: Yeah, it's truly a sub-stack of arguments and as such you don't even know where it ends.

Comment: Thank you! This helps alot.

Comment: It's common use, when some answer *helps a lot*, to mark it as **the answer**, so the responder can get credit for the effort of giving you the time to explain.